# Is there a way to get around "The multi-valued field '[Table X].[Field Y]' is not valid in specified Join clause" with INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm getting an error when I attempt to apply the following SELECT statement in the Row Source for a field I'm using.

```
SELECT [Poems].[ID],
   [Poems].[Title],
   [Poems].[Year Completed],
   [Poem Types].[Poem Type],
   [Poems].[Blog Location]
FROM Poems 
INNER JOIN [Poem Types] 
   ON [Poems].[Poem Type]=[Poem Types].[ID] 
ORDER BY [Title];
```

The error is:

> The multi-valued field '[Poems].[Poem Type]' is not valid in specified
>   Join clause.

The table [Poem Types] was created before I knew how to create a value list. But, actually I'm kind of happy with it now because I've ended up making some changes to the list, which automatically updated all records that use the table, where if I had to do the same with a value list I'd have to go through and update the records individually or with a find and replace. So, the little key table is actually useful.

The field in [Poems] that references the table is a multi-value field, as the error indicates. However, I can't logically see how this means anything since it should just list the existing values, even if there are more than one of them. Not a problem. I've confirmed that the syntax is correct by using a non-multi-value field instead and watching the Listbox populate nicely with the correct values.

So, my question. Is there some fancy around this restriction I could make use of? For instance, there are only a couple of entries in the entire Poems table that use more than one value in this field. I only allow for multiple values because on rare occasions one multi-part poem contains multiple poem types. So, for instance, if it were necessary and Access would allow it, maybe I could filter out those entries that contain multiple values? Or maybe there's some other way?

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you need to write `[Poems].[Poem Type].Value` instead (in the join condition)?

Comment: Can you include the table definitions?

Comment: Awesome. Why don't you post that as the answer so I can give you an up arrow and select it as the answer so you can get some reputation points?

Comment: Not that you need the reputation, raina77ow. :D I just got a look at how pumped you are with them. Still, it would be nice to put an official answer on the question for others who come round with the same question.

Comment: Well, I've just put this piece of advice as an answer, along with a helpful link. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make long story short, you need to use `[Table].[MultiValuedField].Value` syntax when your query targets (in one way or another) specific values stored in that field. [This article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-HA010149297.aspx) explains the difference it'll make in great details.

Comment: Thank you, sir. By the way, if I only wanted to get the first item from the list of values for multi-value fields, is there a way to do this? Something like [Table].[MultiValuedField].Value(0)? I looked for something like this at the page you linked me to, but didn't see it. Thought I should run it by you just in case. :) Thanks again. It's been a pretty steep learning curve for me, but for some reason I really love this database stuff.

Comment: @Zahhar I don't consider addressing individual value of multi-valued field an easy task. See, multivalued fields are actually abstractions over tables used to represent 'n:m' relationships.

Comment: Turns out what I wanted to accomplish was possible using a WHERE EXISTS (clause)=False. Pretty awesome stuff. I've even managed to put together a little form that lets me select a journal from the Publication Venues table and hit enter, which opens a query showing me all poems that are available and passable for submission while excluding those listings that have previously been submitted to the selected periodical. Then it's just a matter of moving down the list and deciding which poems to select for the new submission. The more I get to know Access 2007, the more impressed I am with it.